# How to integerate Jmeter + graylog + mongodb ??

Tags: mongodb, jmeter, grafana, influxdb, graylog

We have all three(Jmeter + graylog +  mongodb) s\w readly installed with me in windows so please give me any reference or idea how to integerate to each other.

Comment: Do you have some particular problem? There seems to be, at least, a good tutorial on JMeter and mongodb [Jmeter mongoDB perfromance testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/mongodb-performance-testing-with-jmeter/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to observe [real-time results](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/realtime-results.html#realtime-results) of your test in Graylog be informed that the current JMeter version [5.2.1](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-2-1-released-td5728641.html) doesn't support storing results to MongoDB out of the box so you might want to consider [InfluxDB](https://www.influxdata.com/products/influxdb-overview/) instead of MongoDB and [Grafana](https://grafana.com/) instead of Graylog

Check out [How to Use Grafana to Monitor JMeter Non-GUI Results](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-grafana-to-monitor-jmeter-non-gui-results/) article for more details.

---

If you have to stay on this Mongo + Graylog stack you can implement your own [BackendListener](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/visualizers/backend/BackendListener.html) which will store JMeter metrics to MongoDB, but you will have to do some Java programming.

Comment: we are not using InfluxDB...We need the integration of jmeter with grafana + graylog with mongodb.

Comment: thanks for response. if you have Java programming code releted to store JMeter metrics to MongoDB please provide us...